# F5 auto SNAT not working

Tags: routing, load-balancer, f5

I have install F5 VM edition to do `SNAT` testing but fail to produce scenario. I have enable `autonat` on VIP (10.10.10.201) and trying to ping google.com from A, B, C machines but ping doesn't work also any machine not able to surf internet. what i am doing wrong?

I can ping 172.16.20.1 IP which is default GW for all internal machine.

```
   Internet
       |
      [sw]---------[Database]
       |
 10.10.10.201
   [BIGIP]
 172.16.20.1
     |
-----+------
|    |     |
A    B     C

A=172.16.20.2
B=172.16.20.3
C=172.16.20.4
```

**EDIT:**  I have added `database` machine and A, B, C accessing them. someone my A, B and C not able to access those database machine. Even i configure `F5` for ALL Traffic allowed, do you thing that is SNAT issue?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

SNAT automap applied to a VIP will only affect traffic that has arrived inbound to the VIP.  It won't affect traffic initiated from your real servers heading outbound.  For that, you will need to create a SNAT Pool.  More information [here](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_configuration_guide_10_0_0/ltm_snat.html#1210773).

Comment: Thanks!! now i can ping Internet IPs, but also i have `EDIT` my question and added `database` which A,B,C access them, but some how its not working. i am not able to access database. i can `telnet` on SQL port and see packet on tcpdumps. Does it related to SNAT issue?